# How to run background service in react native both ios and android

Tags: react-native

I'm try to create a Background service in React-native for both android & ios I'll try so many library but still I'll be not find batter way to develop background service.

Comment: which is the best way to running background service in android and ios using react-native

Answer (score 0):

Did you try with [this way](https://hackernoon.com/easy-os-background-tasks-in-react-native-bc4476c48b8a) I think this will work on both iOS and android

Comment: Yes, I'll try this example but It's not working, please suggest me anything else...